# Nesting dynamic parameters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am working on a function that will insert a row into a SQL database.  It is basically a simple change log to help me track what is changed on my various SQL instances.  As part of this, I want to have the following parameters:

- Timestamp
- Server
- Instance
- Change

I've got the Timestamp, Change, and Server all figured out, but the Instance is giving me some trouble.  The Server parameter is dynamic, as it pulls a list of SQL servers from my inventory.  I then want the value of that parameter to be used in another dynamic parameter, which pulls a list of the instances that are on that server (also from my inventory).  Here is what I have for the dynamic portion:

```
DynamicParam {
    if (!(Get-Module sqlps)){ Pop-Location; Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking; Push-Location }
    $inventoryinstance = 'ServerName'
    $newparams         = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

    $server_query      = 'SELECT [Name] FROM [ServerInventory].[dbo].[Servers] WHERE [TypeID] = 1 ORDER BY [Name]'
    $servers           = Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $inventoryinstance -query $server_query -connectiontimeout 5
    # Populate array
    $serverlist = @()
    foreach ($servername in $servers.Name) { 
        $serverlist += $servername
    }

    $attributes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
    $attributes.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
    $attributes.Position         = 1
    $attributes.Mandatory        = $true
    $attributes.HelpMessage      = "The server the change was made on"

    # Server list parameter setup
    if ($serverlist){ $servervalidationset = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute -ArgumentList $serverlist }
    $serverattributes = New-Object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
    $serverattributes.Add($attributes)
    if ($serverlist){ $serverattributes.Add($servervalidationset) }
    $serverob = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("Server", [String], $serverattributes)
    $newparams.Add("Server", $serverob)

    $instance_query  = "SELECT [Name] FROM [ServerInventory].[dbo].[SQLInstances] WHERE [ServerID] = (SELECT [ServerID] FROM [ServerInventory].[dbo].[Servers] WHERE [Name] = '$($PSBoundParameters.Server)')"
    $instances       = Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $inventoryinstance -query $instance_query -connectiontimeout 5
    # Populate array
    $instancelist = @()
    foreach ($instancename in $instances.Name) { 
        $instancelist += $instancename
    }

    $attributes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
    $attributes.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
    $attributes.Position         = 2
    $attributes.Mandatory        = $false
    $attributes.HelpMessage      = "The instance the change was made on, do not specify for server-level changes"

    # Server list parameter setup
    if ($instancelist){ $instancevalidationset = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute -ArgumentList $instancelist }
    $instanceattributes = New-Object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
    $instanceattributes.Add($attributes)
    if ($instancelist){ $instanceattributes.Add($instancevalidationset) }
    $instanceob = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("Instance", [String], $instanceattributes)
    $newparams.Add("Instance", $instanceob)            

    return $newparams
}
```

Everything seems to be working, except the value for the instance variable doesn't autocomplete.  Is it possible to use the value of one dynamic parameter to generate another?